# whats the best outline for toon/anime outlines, freestyle vs inverted hull method vs some other method i dont know in 2.9?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, freestyle

I'm doing anime style animations, but I'm having trouble figuring out what's the best outline method to use. Keep in mind this is full animations, not an image. I'll also be using 2d plane assets for effects and stuff. I like the detailed look of freestyle, and able to make it look hand drawn, but making it not affect 2d planes and having it outline things behind them is too much of a pain, unless I'm missing something, and I like the inverted hull method for its real time view, but I don't like that I can't be as detailed with it, like with machine like meshes, and I can't make it look hand drawn, unless there's a trick I don't know.

For freestyle, I know I can put it all in collections but do to the sheer amount of assets ill have, that will get messy real quick. You would think liking to a collection that has other collections within it would work, but it doesn't, which makes zero sense. Also, there's the fact ill have to put transparent planes/materials on another layer, which could make things difficult when animating. If its freestyle what's the best way to render/compose it. I know there's different methods like just rendering it and having it separate then combine it in compositing.

So does anyone know which is better, a trick I'm not thinking of or an outline method that I don't know?

I'm using blender 2.9 and the eevee render engine.

Comment: Can this be re-opened. I'm asking what's the best outline to use for anime style animations. I'm giving them as much information as I can, so I can get better help.

Comment: There's nothing I can edit out as I was telling them all the info they would need and why I'm struggling.